# Have anybody ever feel unmotivated working outsource?

Tags: subcontracting, outsourcing

Currently I am working as a subcontractor for this IT company. For the previous period, the work was shared fairly between all the team (outsource and in house employees) depended on team members' skills and work quality. However, now the company want to seperate between the outsource and in house team, for example the subcontractor only get to do the basic manual work and the in house members will get to do some more important tasks. I know that there is nothing wrong or illegal in what they do, but somehow I feel like I lost the motivation to work. Because no matter how good you are or how hard you try you won't get any where better, just because you are not the direct employee from the company.

Have anybody ever experienced the same thing? Do you have any advise for me?

I am trying to find another job but seems like there is nothing available now because of the COVID 19 situation.

Comment: Everyone everywhere eventually gets demotivated by their work. There's lots of advice (and a fair bit here in previous questions) - but what is your goal?

Comment: Is there someone you can talk to about the potential to move in-house?

Answer (score 1):

As a contingent workforce employee, you will miss a lot of learning opportunities. It is a caste system that runs in the IT industry. I would suggest you to prepare well and work in a company that has in-house project. And till then, do not compare. Take this issue to work on yourself. That itself is a great motivation. Believe that you are no less, just that you got channelized in a way you don't like.

Answer (score 1):

> but somehow I feel like I lost the motivation to work.

This is a personal issue you should resolve. Motivation as a subcontractor should not be dependent on the work, it should be dependent on the remuneration.

Especially if you cannot find more interesting work.

I've been in your situation more than once, the remedy is to treat it as a revenue stream and not to worry about the actual tasks given. I'll happily do data entry if anyone wants to pay my hourly rate.

Comment: Life is short, and their are many ways to have a revenue stream and get paid. I turned down at least two cushy jobs with decent pay in my career because I knew it would do nothing for my development, both my career and my self.

Comment: @paulj lucky you, in my country there is 80% unemployment so jobs are not so easy to come by. The jobs that are easy to find are minimum wage, around $1 USD equivalent an hour. That holds true for many other places, especially right now with the COV-ID. OP has already said they can't find another job. So unsure what your point is.